# Work with Controller and Action without sending a redirect?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I have some server side code that runs some rules and than will redirect to differing controllers and actions depending on the outcome of the rules.

Whats the best way to represent a Controller and Action combo without doing the `RedirectToAction("Action","Controller");` because I dont actually want to issue the redirect right after the method executes.

so i want to do something like

```
public SomeObject ApplyRules(){
   if(somecondition){
      return(Action1,Controller1);
   else if(someotherCondition){
      return(Action2,Controller2);
   }
}
```

I can create a class that has two string properties (`Controller`, and `Action`) but I have to think there is some built in class that I should be using to represent this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `RedirectToRouteResult` type and pass it around. You don't have to create new objects or tuples.

```
[NonAction]
private RedirectToRouteResult ApplyRules(){
    if(condition1){
        return RedirectToAction("Action1");
    }
    else if(condition2){
        return RedirectToAction("Action2");
    }
    else return RedirectToAction("Action3")
}

public ActionResult MyAction()
{
    RedirectToRouteResult result = ApplyRules();

    // As long as you don't return your "result" from THIS METHOD
    // redirect won't happen:

    // return result;

    return View();
}
```

As long as you don't return `RedirectResult` from your ACTION method, you can use it as return parameter of your `ApplyRules()` or any other method.

If your `ApplyRules()` method is outside of Controller, you cannot use `RedirectToAction` helper. In that case you can generate `RedirectToRouteResult` like this:

```
var routeValues = new System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary();
routeValues.Add("controller", "Account");
routeValues.Add("action", "Register");
var result = new RedirectToRouteResult(routeValues);
```

Comment: having difficulty resolving RedirectToAction("ActionName);

Comment: nm derr have to extend Controller looks like this is what i wanted.

Comment: If your ApplyRules is not inside of Controller, you can user RouteValueDictionary to create RedirectToRouteResult.

Comment: TY Nenad! Your answer with incorporating RouteValueDictionary is exactly what i was looking for and it helped me remove some smelly code.

Answer (score 1):

I don't normally use tuples, but this could be a situation where it makes sense:

```
public Tuple<string,string> ApplyRules(){
   if(somecondition)
   {
      return(new Tuple<string, string>("Action1","Controller1"));
   }
   else if(someotherCondition)
   {
      return(return(new Tuple<string, string>("Action2","Controller2")););
   }
}
```

Learn more about tuples at [this msdn post](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple.aspx).

You would of course do your redirect, something like this:

```
public void DoMyRedirect(Tuple<string,string> route)
{
  return RedirectToAction(route.Key1, route.Key2);
}
```